# Can we configure tomcat/servlet/java to select windows root drive whenever we refer "/" in paths

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have been working with Eclipse on windows with Java Servlet frameworks And Tomcat in combination for almost Six years now. Whenever I configured tomcat in eclipse to run any Servlet based framework (mostly Struts2/Struts1) and I tried to access paths on disks like for example to set log file path, from the servlet, I assumed that "/" means C: or the drive on which tomcat is running (I always use external installation of tomcat in Eclipse). 
However recently my tomcat selected D: as root drive for path(/var/data/logs). And now it is again selecting C: as root drive for "/" even if my Tomcat and Eclipse installations are running on D: Not sure how root drive is selected whenever we refer to "/" in these scenarios.
I would like to always select D: as my root drive whenever i refer to "/" in my paths.

Ofcourse I don't want to  write a code to check current OS  and then decide the path to use (like "/" or C:/D: etc)

Answer (score 1):

It works just as in the command line.

If in your command line, you're in the directory `c:\foo\bla` and type `cd \`, you'll go to `c:\`. If you're in the directory `d:\foo\bla` and type `cd \`, you'll go to `d:\`. So, the path depends on where you are when the java command starting tomcat is executed.

If you always want to be on d:\, then make sure the .bat file used to start tomcat goes to the `d:` drive before executing its `java` command.

It would be simpler and more reliable to have your build system generate an appropriate absolute path depending on the target deployment platform though: use d:\var\data\logs when generating a war for windows, and use /var/data/logs when generating a war for another OS.